# Courier-imap (authlib) - supported hashes?

Tags: hash, courier-imap

Which hashes are supported by courier-imap (or maybe its courier-authlib job?)?

Ive tried passwords hashed with {SHA}, {SSHA} and {SSHA256}. Only first seems to work, but i need to use last one (ssha256).